# How to make Flash On Screen Keyboard work with windows?

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, flash, windows-7, flash-cs5

I know flash I am making a (SWF)Flash Virtual On Screen Keyboard, I want to use it the same way windows on-screen keyboard is used. But I dont know how to go out of the scope of the flash environment and interact with system elements like windows screen keyboard (osk.exe) does. If anyone knows how i can make that possible do help out.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure there is a file extension that allows you to override system EXE's, I think it may be called `mod`, so save your file as `OSK.exe` and rename it to `OSK.mod` and copy it to the same folder as the system version and it should override it, this may be wrong because I have not done windows programming for quite a while.

You could always modify the registry like: http://geekswithblogs.net/ssimakov/archive/2005/03/22/26930.aspx

Comment: ok I edited the question, I think you misunderstood what I was trying to say.

Comment: I do not think this is possible as it would introduce a massive security risk. For example, if you visit a web site and the Flash/SWF could control system calls like keyboard requests this would be bad.

Comment: Flash is not an application that can perform system calls, flash is a web based object for doing web based actions, if you want to build an OSK application you could try writing it in C++,VB.net,Delphi well anything that can compile and produce an EXE, not like Flash although it produces an EXE its not an application, the EXE it produces is a sandboxed environment designed to play Flash "Movies"

Comment: If flash could do what you ask, it would be an immense security risk, and probably not used by anyone for that reason. Flash is explicitly designed to only interact with a very specific and limited subset of the host system, and generating fake keyboard events is not a part of it.

Comment: Are we talking about flash player in a browser or air app on the desktop?